# why can't i hide DialogBox in UiBinder in GWT?

Tags: gwt, uibinder, dialog, gwtp

in `Test.ui.xml`

```xml
<g:DialogBox ui:field="wishlistDialogBox" autoHide="true">
     <g:caption>Test</g:caption>
     <g:HTMLPanel> some widgets..</g:HTMLPanel>
</g:DialogBox>
```

After running, the application still show the `DialogBox`, so I tried to set hide for "wishlistDialogBox" in `TestView.java` but it didn't work.

```java
  @UiField DialogBox wishlistDialogBox;
  @Inject
  public TestView(final Binder binder) {
        widget = binder.createAndBindUi(this);
        wishlistDialogBox.hide();
   }
```

Then i set hide for it in `TestPresenter.java` but it still didn't work

```java
  @Override
  protected void onBind() {
      super.onBind();
      getView().getWishlistDialogBox().hide();
  }
```

What's wrong, Goodle didn't explain it at all.

In addition, how to reuse the `DialogBox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DialogBox` (and `PopupPanel`s in general) does not work like any other widget when speaking about adding them to the DOM. You should never attach them directly to it (i.e., `panel.add(yourDialogBox)` or inside a `UiBinder` XML file) as you did. Instead you should create them, and simply call `hide()`/`show()`, and the like methods, to get it displayed/hidden (i.e., attached/detached at the end of/from the DOM).

Answer (score 0):

Something that works for me is creating a Dialogbox separately from any other widgets. So it has its own Java file and its own ui.xml file :

**UiBinder xml file:**

```xml
    <ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
      xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    
      <g:DialogBox ui:field="dialog">
        <g:caption>My Dialog</g:caption>
        <g:HTMLPanel> 
          <g:Button ui:field="closeButton" text="close" /> 
        </g:HTMLPanel> 
      </g:DialogBox>
      
    </ui:UiBinder>
```

**Java file:**

```java
    public class MyDialog { // here you do not inherit anything
    
        private static MyDialogUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyDialogUiBinder.class);
    
        interface MyDialogUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyDialog> {
        }
        
        @UiField
        DialogBox dialog;
    
        @UiField
        Button closeButton;

        public MyDialog() {
          // make cast to DialogBox
          dialog = (DialogBox) (uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
        }

    
        public void hide() {
          dialog.hide();
        }
    
        public void show() {
          dialog.center();
        }
    
        @UiHandler("closeButton")
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
          hide();
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Ok, this dialog is good for static message like a prompt or something, but what is we need it to be customised (like add more Widgets into it) then we need to create new DialogBox?

Comment: I first created MyDialog.ui.xml & MyDialog.java using ur code, it worked ok. But when i create a second similar dialog WishListDialogBox.ui.xml & WishListDialogBox.java--> then in there're some errors in  MyDialog.java such as "Field dialog has no corresponding field in template file WishListDialogBox.ui.xml"

Comment: But after i deleted  WishListDialogBox.ui.xml & WishListDialogBox.java, then there was no error in MyDialog.ui.xml & MyDialog.java

Comment: So if i chose ur solution then i can't create many different version of DialogBox?

Comment: Your error sounds like copy paste mistake. You haven't edited ui.xml correctyly ( renaming the ui:field="dialog").

Comment: no, if i removed WishListDialogBox.ui.xml & WishListDialogBox.java, then there no error

Comment: it seems lke Gwt only alow u to create 1 MyDialog like ur code, if u try to create a second one, then they got conflict? do u think so?

Comment: Ur code is fine, working ok, but if u create a second similar  dislogboxs (ex: WishListDialogBox.ui.xml & WishListDialogBox.java), then there is an error

Comment: i found a solution, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471146/gwt-implementing-a-dialogbox-for-login-purposes

this is the right thing to do

Comment: see previous answer "You should never attach dialogbox inside a UiBinder XML file)" so i think ur solution is not 100% optimum

Comment: @Kiti you mistunderstood answer, you are mentioning. You can use DialogBox via UIBinder, but you should NOT attach it inside HTMPLPanel or any other container, rather use it separately. And of course you can make it customizable like any other panel, and any other DialogBox which you create in regular way, coding the structure in Java. UIbinder is just something which helps you create the structure of your widgets - so it looks more clearly and html'y.

Answer (score -1):

Finally i figured out a way, that is to put the `DialogBox` into a invisible `HTMLPanel`

```xml
<g:HTMLPanel visible="false"> 
    <g:DialogBox ui:field="wishlistDialogBox" autoHide="true">
        <g:caption>Test</g:caption>
        <g:HTMLPanel> some widgets..</g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:DialogBox>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Then just call show & hide `DialogBox` as usual & it will show the `DialogBox` even the `DialogBox` was wrapped inside an invisible `HTMLPanel`.

```
getView().getWishlistDialogBox().show();
```

Comment: That's not how `DialogBox` is suppose to be used. You need to do it like @Andrea Boscolo says.